# TS: How use`this.something` inside typeof declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Vue + TypeScript, but I believe this has to do only with TypeScript.

As I am being forced to use

```
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      fields: {
        name: schema.string().required(),
        age: schema.number().required().oneOf([10, 20, 30])
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send(values: any) {
      const fields = this.fields

      type Fields = TypeOf<typeof fields>

      users.create(values as Fields)
    }
  }
})
```

How I would like to use

[image]

Another example with scope of construction function

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to use `typeof this.something` without having to declare a variable to store value of `this.someting`?

Comment: `TypeOf<this['fields']>` should work. You can use `typeof` only on identifiers (variable names) or their properties.

Comment: @AlekseyL. but what I need is to pass the type of some variable into the `TypeOf` that I have created. Example `InferType<typeof this.variableHere>`. `typeof this ['variableHere']` does not work because `this` is unknown, see [this image](https://i.ibb.co/C1wdjFf/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-20-a-s-01-17-00.png) 
here is the [typescript playground](https://bityli.com/haeXa) if you want to test

Comment: Oh, I see. `this` as a type can be used only within class/interface

Comment: In your last example you are using `this` inside arrow function. What type of `this` are you expect?